# Login with jQuery AJAX is not working

Tags: php, ajax

```
function do_login()
{
$('.loginsubmit').click(function(e)
{
    var datum=$('.loginform').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: datum,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data.prop=="false")
            {
                $('p#login-error-notif').text(data.error);
            }
            else if(data.prop=="true")
            {
                $('#logindrp span').text("Welcome "+data.name);
            }
        }
    });            
});
} //closing do_login function
```

This is the function called when user click on the Login the button. The error I see is the Uncaught reference error: 'prop' of null.

The code in the PHP page is

```
        if(isset($_POST['username']))
        {
         $username=$_POST['username']

...// proceed with checking the username and password

    if($check_login)
    {
    $return=array(prop=>"true", name=>$name, username=>$username);  
        echo json_encode($return);  
    }
            else
            {
            $return=array(prop=>"false", error=>"Invalid username/password.");  
        echo json_encode($return);
            }


        }
```

But I observed this part is not being executed. I mean the 'username' is not sent to the page. I checked it with adding the code `setcookie("username", $username);` inside it. The cookie is never created. What is the problem in my AJAX request?

Comment: Obiviously `username` is not in `datum`. But what data is? Check with sth like `$.each(datum, function(key, value) { alert(key +' => '+ value); });`

Comment: have you used var_dump the post and then use the ajax to out put the data on screen to check what values have been submitted?

Comment: @AmazingDreams: datum is serialized with `username` and `password`. Also I passed username and password individually. But no use.

Comment: Fix `data: datum` and add php last json echo to question.

Comment: What do you get when you log `data` ?

Comment: Can you debug the ajax call with chrome's dev tools? (or something similar? Maybe the url is wrong and you're getting a 404 error.

Comment: With firebug tab Net you can see the request when you log in from a website. This can give you more information

Comment: Error I see in chrome Developer tools

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null script.js:270
$.ajax.success script.js:270
n
o.fireWith
w
d`

Comment: try without "contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"," this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked well after resolving the following errors:

1. `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` Thank you **marteljn**.
2. Enclosing the variables `prop`, `error`, `username` in single codes.

Answer (score 1):

The `contentType` property in your AJAX call sets the format of the data sent to the server.  By default PHP won't accept JSON.  Remove the contentType line from your AJAX call.

By default JQuery sends the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`, which is likely what your PHP script likely needs to fill the `$_POST` array properly.

This explains why your username value is not getting set.  This is also a very common mistake that people make all of the time.

Comment: Thank you @marteljn, on removing the line I can see the cookie is getting set. But I am not getting the response back from JSON. Still I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of null`

Comment: @SuryaS I think you are trying to access it the wrong way. Do a `success: function(data){console.log(data)` and post the output.

Comment: @SuryaS it looks like maybe those if blocks are not getting hit meaning that no output is getting outputted as JSON.

Comment: I have found the error. Seems the `prop` and `error` must be enclosed within quotes :) Thank you @marteljn